# ASP.NET MVC3 Razor - Maintain scroll position on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, scroll, postback, position

How can i maintain scroll position on postback after sorting a grid table that uses MvcContrib framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way is to use some javascript to set the current scroll position to a hidden field, then restore that position on page load (usually in a jquery ready event).

However, that's really just a side effect.  You should be doing some kind of ajax command to update the grid rather than a postback, then no scrolling required.

Comment: This solution is great but i was wondering if i could find something better and easier, like the property MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback=true in ASP.NET Web Forms. I'm using the MVC Contrib grid with search filters and sorting so i expected a built-in solution but i can't find it...

Comment: Yea I agree with Mast3r. Nothing says that we "must" use Ajax. I find using viewmodels in mvc 4 with postback much much faster to develop and easier to maintain. If browsers caching is enabled you don't even see the page flick! solution at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2618726/706363

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery and client side cookie.

```
$(function(){
  var posName = location.href + "_top";
  $(window).unload(function() {
    var top = $(document).scrollTop();
    $.cookie(posName, top);
  });

  var goTop = parseInt($.cookie(posName));
  if (goTop) {
    $(document).scrollTop(goTop);
    $.cookie(posName, "");
  }
});
```

Hope this code.

Comment: That would mean the browser would scroll even if you moved to a different page.  I think it's better to use a hidden input, since that will stay on the current page only.

Answer (score 0):

A useful solution is posted here : http://www.experts-exchange.com/Hardware/Servers/Q_28082177.html

```
$(function(){

        var top = parseInt($.cookie("top"));
        if(top) $(document).scrollTop(top);
        $(document).scroll(function() {
            var top = $(document).scrollTop();
            $.cookie("top", top);
        })
    });
```

This is a very old thread but I have posted this for developer who will be searching for this kind of issue, may help.