# c# asp.net page jitters/jumps/lags on update while scrolling

Tags: c#, asp.net, scroll, updatepanel

If I am scrolling my page and the update gets triggered by the timer the page/scrollposition slightly jumps/jitters/lags. I am using `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack`on my pages and it works fine if I am stationary somewhere on the page, no jump/jitter/lag on update then. Any ideas on how to fix it while scrolling too? Maybe pause the timer while scrolling if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2618726/6320872). For lazy people:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.scrollTo = function( x,y ) 
{
    return true;
}
</script>
```

Just put this in your .aspx file.

Answer (score 0):

There is workaround for that issue.
You pass to controller element you had focus on and then on page load you focus back to that element.

Find focus:

```
var focusedElement = document.activeElement;
```

focusedElement  you send to server (controller or whatever) via post/get or something.

Focus back on page load:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#" + recivedFocusedElement).focus();
}
```

recivedFocusedElement you recive from server.

Comment: What would `document` be here? My page is pretty simple, it is a table filled with server statuses. The table is placed in an updatepanel and that's about it.